# request array in MPI non-blocking send/recv

Tags: fortran, mpi, nonblocking

I am trying to reproduce [this](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/mpiexmpl/src/exchange/C/nonblock/main.html) C example in Fortran. my code so far:

```
use mpi

implicit none
integer, parameter :: maxn = 8
integer, allocatable :: xlocal(:,:)

integer :: i, j, lsize, errcnt, toterr, buff

integer :: ierror, nproc, pid, root = 0, nreq = 0
integer, allocatable :: request(:), status(:,:)

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, pid, ierror)

if (mod(maxn, nproc) /= 0) then
    write(*,*) 'Array size (maxn) should be a multiple of the number of processes'
    call MPI_ABORT(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, ierror)
end if

lsize = maxn/nproc

allocate(xlocal(0:lsize+1, maxn))
allocate(request(nproc))
allocate(status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE,nproc))

xlocal(0,:) = -1
xlocal(1:lsize,:) = pid
xlocal(lsize+1,:) = -1

! send down unless on bottom
if (pid < nproc-1) then
    nreq = nreq + 1
    call MPI_ISEND(xlocal(lsize,:), maxn, MPI_INTEGER, &
                  pid+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request(nreq), ierror)
    write(*,'(2(A,I1),A)') 'process ', pid, ' sent to process ', pid+1, ':'
    write(*,*) xlocal(lsize,:)
end if

if (pid > 0) then
    nreq = nreq + 1
    call MPI_IRECV(xlocal(0,:), maxn, MPI_INTEGER, &
                  pid-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request(nreq), ierror)
    write(*,'(2(A,I1),A)') 'process ', pid, ' received from process ', pid-1, ':'
    write(*,*) xlocal(0,:)
end if

! send up unless on top
if (pid > 0) then
    nreq = nreq + 1
    call MPI_ISEND(xlocal(1,:), maxn, MPI_INTEGER, &
                  pid-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request(nreq), ierror)
    write(*,'(2(A,I1),A)') 'process ', pid, ' sent to process ', pid-1, ':'
    write(*,*) xlocal(1,:)
end if

if (pid < nproc-1) then
    nreq = nreq + 1
    call MPI_IRECV(xlocal(lsize+1,:), maxn, MPI_INTEGER, &
                  pid+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request(nreq), ierror)
    write(*,'(2(A,I1),A)') 'process ', pid, ' received from process ', pid+1, ':'
    write(*,*) xlocal(lsize+1,:)
end if

call MPI_WAITALL(nreq, request, status, ierror)

! check results
errcnt = 0
do i = 1, lsize
    do j = 1, maxn
        if (xlocal(i,j) /= pid) errcnt = errcnt + 1
    end do
end do
do j = 1, maxn
    if (xlocal(0,j) /= pid-1) errcnt = errcnt + 1
    if ((pid < nproc-1) .and. (xlocal(lsize+1,j) /= pid+1)) errcnt = errcnt + 1
end do

call MPI_REDUCE(errcnt, toterr, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)

if (pid == root) then
    if (toterr == 0) then
        write(*,*) "no errors found"
    else
        write(*,*) "found ", toterr, " errors"
    end if
end if

deallocate(xlocal)
deallocate(request)
deallocate(status)

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
```

but i am running into segmentation faults and can not figure out why. I have a feeling it is due to the request array. can someone explain the correct way of using the request array in Fortran? none of the references I found clarify this.

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you haven't already done so, consider compiling your program with some flags that will help you in debugging, e.g. with `gfortran`, you can use `-O0 -g -fbounds-check` (if that does not help, you might add `-fsanitize=address` for versions >= 4.8). Other compilers have similar options for debugging.

Doing that, and running with 2 processes, you program crashes at the `MPI_Reduce` line. If you look up the specifications (e.g. [OpenMPI 1.8](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/)) you can see that this subroutine requires one more argument, i.e., you forgot to add the `ierror` argument at the end.

It is a bit tragic that even though the subprograms from the mpi module are accessible through a `use` association, and thus should be checked for argument consistency to avoid these trivial errors, not all subprograms are necessarily in that module. I don't know which MPI implementation you use, but I checked my local MPICH installation and it does not have most subroutines in the module, so no explicit interfaces exist for them. I guess you are in a similar situation, but I guess other implementations might suffer a similar fate. You could compare it to the C header file missing the function prototype for `MPI_Reduce`. I guess the reason for this is that originally there was only a Fortran 77 interface for most implementations.

Some final comments: be careful not to just copy-paste the C code. The arrays you pass are not contiguous and will result in a temporary copy to be passed to the MPI routines, which is very inefficient (not that it really matters in this case).

Comment: thx for the answer and the tips on the flags, and the arrays! Weird tho; the code worked fine with blocking send/recv.

Comment: offtopic: what does -fsanitize=address do exactly?

Comment: it activates the use of this: https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer